# how we can select two columns having different collation

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table2
```

where `col1` and `col2` are strings and using collations.

When I run the query it shows the error:

1. Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in statement.
2. Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 2 in statement.

Any one please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the error a difference in case sensitivity between the two tables? That is the error that I have most often seen.
If so, collate the offending table back to good old `Latin1_General_CI_AS` or whatever else is most appropriate.

For example, if Table1 was case sensitive and you want to collate both tables as if they were case insensitive:

```
SELECT Col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 
       Col2 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM Table2
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go. Unless there are cases when it's impossible to apply a different collation. Do you happen to know if that is possible, by the way?