# Linked server reference "Invalid Column Name"

Tags: sql, ssms, ssms-2012

In SSMS 2012, I have created a linked server in SERVERA to SERVERB from which I have successfully written queries to multiple tables within the DBB database using a four part reference.

When I try to reference the 'Charge' table in the 'DBB' database with a simple select statement:

```
SELECT * FROM [SERVERB].[DBB].dbo.Charge
```

I get the following message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Invalid column name 'charge_type'.

This column exists in the DBB database as 'Charge_Type', however, the collation of SERVERB is case insensitive, whereas the collation of SERVERA is case sensitive (which is where, I believe, my problem lies).

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Interesting. Can you select a single column rather than `*`? Any computed columns on that table? It's a table and not a view, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/496840/1821329

Comment: @Blorgbeard Even if I specify a singular column, I still get the same message.  It is a table and I don't believe there are any computed columns.

Comment: I should mention SERVERA is 2012 and SERVERB is 2008 R2, and the Charge_Type column is a tinyint data type.

Comment: @FutbolFan Thanks for the response.  I *kind of* understand the collation issue.  Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: @Will_C Personally, I haven't had to deal with this kind of situation before. I apologize, but I thought the link would help a little bit. Although I would try to change the collation on `SERVERA` and see if it works.

Comment: I was able to get around this by creating a view on SERVERB that excluded Charge_Type and querying the view, but that was really just a Band-Aid.  If anyone can help with this, I'd still like to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

*(For the people who might end up here)*

You can change the collation on the fly. In this case, you have to write the name of the column names in the select query. What I mean is, 
rather than writing query like this:

`SELECT * FROM [SERVERB].[DBB].dbo.Charge`

write the query like this:

`SELECT Charge_Col1, Charge_Col2, Charge_Type COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS FROM [SERVERB].[DBB].dbo.Charge`

There is another post similar to this: [how we can select two columns having different collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387546/how-we-can-select-two-columns-having-different-collation)